# how do I can implement that gif animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

This is the animation that I want to implement this animation from youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rx3KwwQaOtU).

I maked first part and just Im stuck on begining of the animation. Just dont know is here usefull use JS or another library, or just CSS.
Better you just download whole archive with my project cuz it has many png files for animation.
Here the archive of project

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let sack = $(".sack"),
        leaf = $(".leaf"),
        bonus = $(".bonus"),
        water = $(".water"),
        wheat = $(".wheat"),
        timer = $('.timer'),
        beer = $('.beer'),
        content = $('.content'),
        container = $('.container'),
        text = $('.header p:first-child'),
        header = $('.header'),
        logo = $('.logo'),
        width = $(window).width(),
        height = $(window).height();
    setTimeout(()=>{
        sack.animate({'top': '-100px','left': '-80px'}, 500);
        wheat.animate({'top': '-80px','right': '-80px'}, 500);
        water.animate({'top': '0px', 'margin-left': '-27px'}, 500);
        bonus.animate({'top': '-190px', 'right': '-10px'}, 500);
        leaf.animate({'top': '-230px'}, 500);
        timer.animate({'opacity': 0}, 400);
        beer.animate({'bottom': '65px'}, 500);

        setTimeout(()=> {
            if (height >= 670) {
                content.css({'transform': 'translate(59px, 155px)'})
            } else if (height >= 633) {
                content.css({'transform': 'translate(59px, 135px)'})
            } else if (height >= 620) {
                content.css({'transform': 'translate(59px, 125px)'})
            } else if (height >= 550) {
                content.css({'transform': 'translate(59px, 85px)'})
            }
            // console.log(height)
            // content.css({'transform': 'translate(59px, 155px)'})
            // container.css({'background-position': '0 100px'});
            setTimeout(()=> {
                // leaf.attr("src","../images/itemleafm.png");
                // leaf.css({'top': '-230px','margin': '-47px auto','right': '123px', 'position': 'absolute'})
                beer.attr("src","https://i.ibb.co/2WJpCpQ/bankaf.png");


                setTimeout(()=> {
                    container.css({'background': 'url(https://i.ibb.co/47Lny0p/supermarket.png', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size':'cover'});
                    sack.animate({'margin-left': '-180px'}, 500);
                    wheat.animate({'margin-right': '-180px'}, 500);
                    water.animate({'margin-left': '-127px'}, 500);
                    bonus.animate({'margin-right': '-110px'}, 500);
                    header.css({'padding-bottom':'150px'});
                    text.css({'transition':'1s'});
                    text.css({'margin-top':'-150px'});
                    logo.css({'top': '0'});
                    leaf.css({'opacity': 0});
                }, 1000)
            }, 1000)
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
    

})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(24, 60, 112, 0.9), rgba(24, 60, 112, 0.9)), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('https://i.ibb.co/47Lny0p/supermarket.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: -18px -122px;
    background-size: 300px;
    background-position: 0 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: background-image 1s;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    
}

.logo {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #183C70 23.14%, rgba(24, 60, 112, 0) 100%);
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: -200px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
}
.logo img {
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
}
.header,
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header p:first-child {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;  
    margin-top: 30px;  
}
.header p:last-child {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.content {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 300px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.footer {
    text-align: right;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
.line-one, 
.line-two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

img[alt='wheat'] {
    position: absolute;
}

img[alt='sack'] {
      top: 30px;
      right: 30px;
      position: absolute;
}
img[alt='water'] {
    margin: 31px auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-self: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
img[alt='bonus'] {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
img[alt='leaf'] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 60px;

}
.footer img:first-child {
    opacity: .6;
}
img.beer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -170px;
}
@media (max-height: 600px) {
    .header p:last-child {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .header p:first-child {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Beer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="background-size: cover;background-position: center;">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6X3QHs3/Logo.png" width="90" height="63" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="header after">
            <p>Вращай смартфон, собери как </br> можно больше ингредиентов за </br> 60 секунд и узнай секретный </br> ингредиент!</p>
            <p class="timer">60</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="line-one">
                <img class="wheat" src="https://i.ibb.co/6ZYTvvb/itemw.png" alt="wheat">
                <img class="water" width="50" height="90" src="https://i.ibb.co/Sxnz4j8/itemwat.png" alt="water">
                <img class="sack" src="https://i.ibb.co/N1ch8ZC/items.png" alt="sack">
            </div>
            <div class="line-two">
                <img class="leaf" src="https://i.ibb.co/2PmkYFc/iteml.png" alt="leaf">
                <img class="bonus" src="https://i.ibb.co/JpKZjGK/itemb.png" alt="bonus">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <img class="seal" src="https://i.ibb.co/C8WQngb/seal.png" alt="seal">
            <img class="beer" src="https://i.ibb.co/hCghLdh/banka.png" width="74" height="180" alt="beer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The animation only for mobile devices so you should look by inspector with width less than 400px and height less than 650
Here I have the problems with adaptive animation and z-index on leaf. It should be over beer,  does not work.

Then you should noticed that there are several interaption in animation.
Please just need advice and little help to continue the work

Comment: all files in my google disk so you can just download it

Comment: I would recommend uploading and embedding the image in the example image in the question and posting an [mcve] rather than linking to your whole source code.  For security reasons I doubt anyone is going to download something directly from your Google Drive...

Comment: Like @AlexanderNied I don't particularly want to be downloading a "gif" from an unknown person's google drive.